# SwiftUI: determine if view is overlaid by another view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a generic Popup that I display as an `overlay` above of my `View`.

Is there a way to notify my `View` when the `overlay` is displayed or dismissed from my `View`?

The built in `onAppear` and `onDisappear` obviously aren't relevant in my case as the `lifecycle` state of the `View` does not change due to an overlay displayed above.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: and using onAppear and onDisappear of the overlay or even onDismiss ?

Comment: It would be helpful to share some code.